# Target database not working with NLog 3.1 and Windsor Castle Logging Facility

Tags: nlog

I'm able to log to a file using NLog, but the database is not created and if I create it manually, doesn't log anything.

Is there something I might be missing?

This is my NLog.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

```
<target name="database" xsi:type="Database">
  <connectionString>
    Server=.\SQLEXPRESS; Database=Logging; User Id=user; Password=password;
  </connectionString>
  <commandText>
    insert into LogEntries(Date,Level,Logger,Message,MachineName, UserName, Callsite, ThreadId, Exception, InnerException, Stacktrace, ErrorSource, ErrorClass, ErrorMethod, ErrorMessage, InnerErrorMessage) values(@time_stamp, @level, @logger, @message,@machinename, @user_name, @call_site, @threadid, @log_exception, @log_innerexception, @stacktrace, @ErrorSource, @ErrorClass, @ErrorMethod, @ErrorMessage, @InnerErrorMessage);
  </commandText>
  <parameter name="@time_stamp" layout="${longdate}"/>
  <parameter name="@level" layout="${level:uppercase=true}"/>
  <parameter name="@logger" layout="${logger}"/>
  <parameter name="@message" layout="${message}"/>
  <parameter name="@machinename" layout="${machinename}"/>
  <parameter name="@user_name" layout="${windows-identity:domain=true}"/>
  <parameter name="@call_site" layout="${callsite:filename=true}"/>
  <parameter name="@threadid" layout="${threadid}"/>
  <parameter name="@ErrorSource" layout="${event-context:item=error-source}" />
  <parameter name="@ErrorClass" layout="${event-context:item=error-class}" />
  <parameter name="@ErrorMethod" layout="${event-context:item=error-method}" />
  <parameter name="@ErrorMessage" layout="${event-context:item=error-message}" />
  <parameter name="@InnerErrorMessage" layout="${event-context:item=inner-error-message}" />
  <parameter name="@log_exception" layout="${exception:format=type,message,method:maxInnerExceptionLevel=5:innerFormat=shortType,message,method}"/>
  <parameter name="@log_innerexception" layout="${exception:method:maxInnerExceptionLevel=5:innerFormat=shortType,message,method}"/>
  <parameter name="@stacktrace" layout="${stacktrace}"/>
  <dbProvider>System.Data.SqlClient</dbProvider>
  <install-command>
    <text>CREATE DATABASE Logging</text>
    <connectionString>Server=.\SQLEXPRESS; Database=master; User Id=user; Password=password;</connectionString>
    <ignoreFailures>true</ignoreFailures>
  </install-command>

  <install-command>
    <text>
      CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LogEntries](
      [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
      [Level] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
      [Message] [varchar](4095) NOT NULL,
      [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
      [Logger] [varchar](200) NULL,
      [MachineName] [varchar](100) NULL,
      [UserName] [varchar](100) NULL,
      [CallSite] [varchar](100) NULL,
      [ThreadId] [varchar](100) NULL,
      [Exception] [varchar](max) NULL,
      [InnerException] [varchar](max) NULL,
      [Stacktrace] [varchar](max) NULL,
      ErrorSource [varchar](max) NULL, 
      ErrorClass [varchar](max) NULL, 
      ErrorMethod [varchar](max) NULL, 
      ErrorMessage [varchar](max) NULL, 
      InnerErrorMessage [varchar](max) NULL,
      CONSTRAINT [PK_Logs] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
      ([Id] ASC)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
      ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
    </text>
  </install-command>

   <!--commands to uninstall database--> 
  <uninstall-command>
    <text>DROP DATABASE Logging</text>
    <connectionString>Server=.\SQLEXPRESS; Database=master; User Id=user; Password=user;</connectionString>
    <ignoreFailures>true</ignoreFailures>
  </uninstall-command>
</target>
```

Comment: Have you manually also created the `LogEntries` table?

Comment: Yes, I did, and I've checked that the user is the owner of the db, and can create tables

Comment: So if the table is there it is still not logging? In this case try to turn on the internal logging https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging to see what is wrong. Or your problem is that the database and the table is not automatically created?

Comment: Both, I think...they're not automatically created, and if manually created, nothing is logged. I'll try the internal logging

Comment: @nemesv thx! Didn't know about the internal-logging! With that I checked that the problem was a string too long. I've changed the column to varchar(max) and a datetime column to datetim2 and now it works!
If you write it as an answer, I'll mark it as the correct one.

Comment: @nemesv BTW...The table is not being automatically created...Do I need to configure something more? The internal log says: "MyLoggingDb requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'myuser'." but that's actually when the CREATE TABLE must be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have any kind of troubles with Nlog it is always a good starting point to turn on the [internal logging](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging) with adding this to your nlog.config's root element:

```
<nlog internalLogFile="c:\log.txt" internalLogLevel="Trace">
```

In your concrete configuration the `install-command` are not run automatically because NLOG does not run them by itself.

You need to use a command line tool called `InstallNLogConfig.exe` which runs these commands with calling:

```
InstallNLogConfig.exe c:\path\to\NLog.config
```

If you have installed NLog with nuget you can find this command in

```
\packages\NLog.{version}\tools\{yourFrameworkVersion}\InstallNLogConfig.exe
```

You can read more about the here: [Deploying NLog configuration files](http://nlog-project.org/2010/09/25/deploying-nlog-configuration.html)

Comment: I have the NLog 3.2.0.0 nupkeg insalled, but there is no tools folder.  Is there another nupkeg that includes it, was it removed?

Comment: Strangely it was removed from the nuget package with this commit: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/commit/06233c411e8ecbf633d05a8a41c85c6e4cd10bde. You can still get it from installing Nlog 2.1 with `Install-Package NLog -Version 2.1.0`